# Google's AdMob on Meteor.js / Cordova is not defined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, meteor, admob

I am developing a mobile app for android platforms with Meteor.js

I'm nearly finished so I wanted to implement Google AdMob to my application. I couldn't find any package for Meteor on Atmosphere so I directly used Cordova plugin with directives you can see here: [com.google.cordoca.admob](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.google.cordova.admob) and here: [Meteor Cordova Integration](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration)

I'm using iron:router with Meteor. and my Meteor version is 1.0.

However, I can't make it work in anywhere. I've tried Iron Router actions, client.js and in server.js with startup function. No chance at all. The problem is AdMob variable is not accessible from javascript and I have no idea where to access.

Any solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone stumbles upon on it;

I've figured out the problem. It was caused by an interruption during building process. So I deleted cordova-build folders and build again. It worked without a problem when I call from router action.